# Can not extract year with DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to extract the year of a input date like

```
$start = $request->input('start');

$refYear = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start)->format("Y");
```

But I'm having the error `Call to a member function format() on boolean` and i saw another answers but nothing result so far.

Where start is defined as a input in my page

```
<input id="start" type="text" name="start" class="date-type"
                placeholder="dd-mm-aaaa"><i class="fi-calendar" style="top: 2px;"></i>
```

In my table the startDate column is a date time like '2017-10-26 00:00:00.000' and refyear is a int (2017).

Comment: it seems you forgot the microseconds, try changing the format to `"Y-m-d H:i:s.u"`and print the refYear value, it should be 2017 for your sample date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `Carbon` instead:

```
$refYear = Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start)->format("Y");
```

But also your format is wrong you are missing `.u` based on your example of the date field. You should use this:

```
$refYear = Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s.u", $start)->format("Y");
```

Comment: @nakov Is carbon in the core or do you have to install it as a third party library?

Comment: it is with Laravel, so you should just import it on top of the class: `use Carbon\Carbon;`

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation DateTime::createFromFormat:

> Returns a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure.

This is why you call it on a boolean, because the value is false.

Your format seems to be correct, that means `createFromFormat` can not handle your `$start` . Your input does not match your format, make sure it matches.

The following for instance works:

```
echo (DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2019-01-01 12:30:30"))->format("Y"); // result: 2019
```

@jeprubio from the comments is right btw. - add the milliseconds to match your given format:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s.u", "2017-10-26 00:00:00.000")->format("Y"); // 2017
```